# poor usenet connection although HTTP is fine?

Tags: windows-7, usenet

I'm trying to fix my friends system.

They have a fresh install of Windows 7, Grabit (usenet reader/download) and a subscription to astraweb and a newly updated router frimware. They are connected to the router via wireless, although it has been tested with an ethernet cable as well.

While downloading via Grabit, the speed maxes out between 10 - 20kbs or 90-100kbs and often starts and stops. Speeds should be in the 3200kbs area.

My setup connects and downloads at full speed despite using the same connection, same OS, same subscription and same version of Grabit.

A speed test reports expected results and a HTTP download of a large file such as a linux distro quickly maxes the connection speed. I think uTorrent might be suffering from the same problem although I've not tested it properly yet.

I'm convinced it must be something else on the system, but I cannot work out what.

I know it isn't these:

router, internet connection, usenet, subscription, firewall, downloading software, ssl issue, incompatible OS

I'm spent, any ideas?

edit:
it turns out that the problem was uTorrent. I had tested without it running and nothing changed. Upon removal, everything seemed to work fine. weird.

Comment: "Speeds should be in the 3200kbs area." - why? Could it be an upstream network issue to that host? E.g. you friend's ISP has a different performance profile (e.g. is limiting NNTP performance due to its use for file sharing).

Comment: Because that's what it was, and that's what I get using the same setup on his own connection. I had the two systems side by side ensuring all the settings were the exact same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that the problem was uTorrent. I had tested grabit without uTorrent running and the problem persisted. Upon the removal of uTorrent, everything seemed to work fine. weird.